# Incredibly bad M.2 SSD performance (HP OMEN with Samsung XP941)

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd

I have a new laptop (HP Omen) and have just, after great trials and tribulations, installed Kubuntu on it. The install is a dualboot install along with the factory Win8.1 installation using EFI mode.

However, things that hit the SSD (a shiny new 512MB M.2 drive) are obscenely slow: "sudo apt-get install vim" has been running for about ten minutes now, for instance.

Using hdparm to get a speed test gives the following:

```
# hdparm -Tt --verbose /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   1250 MB in  2.00 seconds = 625.01 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:   4 MB in  3.20 seconds =   1.25 MB/sec
```

So something is clearly going wrong. The drive is

```
# lspci | grep SATA
07:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd XP941 PCIe SSD (rev 01)
```

and hdparm says

```
# hdparm /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 multcount     =  0 (off)
 IO_support    =  1 (32-bit)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 62260/255/63, sectors = 1000215216, start = 0
```

I'm not sure about the elevator; I can't check that atm, but at the very least not having elevator=noop shouldn't cause performance to be *this* bad.

There was something intriguing in dmesg:

```
[   18.042832] irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[   18.042838] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 3.16.0-23-generic #31-Ubuntu
[   18.042839] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP OMEN Notebook PC 15/2332, BIOS F.05 10/09/2014
[   18.042840]  ffff8802533360a4 ffff88025f243e60 ffffffff8277fcbc ffff880253336000
[   18.042843]  ffff88025f243e88 ffffffff820d2452 ffff880253336000 0000000000000000
[   18.042845]  0000000000000010 ffff88025f243ec0 ffffffff820d2817 0000000000000000
[   18.042847] Call Trace:
[   18.042848]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff8277fcbc>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[   18.042858]  [<ffffffff820d2452>] __report_bad_irq+0x32/0xd0
[   18.042860]  [<ffffffff820d2817>] note_interrupt+0x267/0x2b0
[   18.042862]  [<ffffffff820cfdf3>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x133/0x1a0
[   18.042863]  [<ffffffff820cfe9d>] handle_irq_event+0x3d/0x60
[   18.042865]  [<ffffffff820d3471>] handle_fasteoi_irq+0x81/0x170
[   18.042869]  [<ffffffff8201577e>] handle_irq+0x1e/0x40
[   18.042872]  [<ffffffff8278aafd>] do_IRQ+0x4d/0xe0
[   18.042875]  [<ffffffff8278896d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[   18.042875]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8261915c>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x4c/0xc0
[   18.042882]  [<ffffffff826192b7>] cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
[   18.042886]  [<ffffffff820b9b77>] cpu_startup_entry+0x347/0x480
[   18.042888]  [<ffffffff82045ac0>] start_secondary+0x230/0x2c0
[   18.042890] handlers:
[   18.042907] [<ffffffffc01c5d80>] ahci_interrupt [libahci]
[   18.042908] Disabling IRQ #16
```

Following up on that, this looks like an IRQ conflict:

```
$ sudo lspci -v | grep "IRQ 16" -B 2 -A 8
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2332
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at b2000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
--
07:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd XP941 PCIe SSD (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a811
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d1600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Expansion ROM at d1610000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
```

I'm trying to figure out now how to resolve this IRQ conflict in the hope that this will help...

Comment: what SSD version is it? because the 840 has had previously reported problems, that occur over time.

Comment: What format did you use for the disk, and which elevator are you running?

Comment: Have you replaced the original SSD with the XP941 or is this the standard configuration for this device? If it's not standard then please check with the original SSD. Also have a look at `/var/log/dmesg` and see if you can find something related to the SSD being detected, or post the log.

Comment: I have a standard Samsung SSD 840 Pro on SATA port. It shows disk reads 472.99 MB/sec, but since on SATA port is using Intel driver. Is the issue then related to Samsung driver? Do not know internal differences with mSata connections to motherboard. I thought they were supposed to be good. On my old system my USB2 flash drives with about 16 MB/sec, so something is not correct somewhere.

Comment: It's a Samsung XP941; it came stock with the machine.

There are interesting things in dmesg that point to an IRQ conflict with the GPU; once I figure out how to post a longer comment here I will add them.

Comment: Check in your BIOS for a "legacy" option. The IRQ conflict could easily kill your performance.

Comment: By "legacy" do you mean "BIOS mode as opposed to UEFI mode", or a legacy IRQ assignment mode? HP, in their hilarious lack of wisdom, has given this thing a BIOS that is remarkably utility-free.

Comment: @entropius Have you managed to solve this problem?? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So I had the same problem (on Arch Linux) and this was the only thread I could on the problem, so I'll post my answer here.

The problem is indeed related to the graphics and is not specific to Ubuntu, but happened on any distro I tried. Ubuntu fall-back works due to the `nomodeset` kernel option. If you're going to install Ubuntu I recommend setting that flag for the LiveCD as well, because otherwise GParted and the installer take forever.

Once installed make sure you set the `nomodeset` option on boot, so that you can install the necessary software:

The problem was solved for me by installing the Intel/Nvidia drivers and enabling bumblebee/bbswitch. This way the Nvidia graphics card is disabled on boot, so that no conflict occurs. Optirun/primusrun still work without a conflict after removing the `nomodeset` option.

On an unrelated note: To make Wifi work on the laptop you need to blacklist the `acer_wmi` module.